# Why my ribbon contents hides automatically?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Ribbon content hides when  clicked on files and library
[image: Ribbon content hides when clicked on files and library]

Contents not showing when clicked on files and library
[image: Contents not showing when clicked on files and library]

Comment: Do you have any other web part on the page? The ribbon is context sensitive.

Comment: I have app parts but not on that page. This page shows all the list templates

Comment: Any JS errors when the page is shown ? How about a custom master page - or some additional custom jQuery, etc ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Master page is customized to Hide the ribbons. Surely there is some custom css or scripts implemented in the page which is hiding the section.Or press F12 and check if you have **.ms-cui-tabBody** mentioned anywhere in the script as display hidden.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that you have some custom CSS which is responsible for hiding content. I suggest you to go through developer toolbar and console log/script profiling to check for javascript errors. Still not agree, please create another site collection and check if you got the same error.